# left and right border are not taking whole screen

Tags: html, css

Not sure whether its a duplicate or not-why my left and right border are not taking whole screen.

ojs.monojitbanerjee.co.cc.

structure is:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id ="main">
```

the border is coming upto main part.but i want to be it upto container or body part.

Comment: do you mean left and right side of body or full height of page upto the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only tested this in Firefox and Chrome, but if you add 100% height to both body, and html, the borders go the height of the browser:

```
html, body{
height:100%;
}
```